# jquery dilaog not showing view no 404 just blank screen mvc 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Why is my dialog not popping?

jQuery

```
    $('.ITA').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    draggable: true,
    width: 400,
    resizable: false,
    dialogClass: "ui-dialog",
    modal: true,
   // show: { effect: 'fade', duration: 300 }
  });

 $(".AllItemsBtn").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   // $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    alert(url);
    $('.ITA').load(url, function () {
        $('.ITA').dialog("open");

    });
   });
```

Controller

```
  public ActionResult GetItemsToAdd()
    {
        var Uid = WebSecurity.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);

        var UserItems = from i in db.Items
                        where i.user_id == Uid 
                        select i;

        var results = UserItems;

        return PartialView("_AllItemsPartial", UserItems );
    }
```

VIEW _AllItemPartial: the view to load into the dialog

```
@model IEnumerable<Item>

<style>
.ui-dialog,.ui-dialog,.ui-widget, 
.ui-widget-content, .ui-corner-all, 
.ui-draggable, 
.ui-resizable {background-color:#ffd800 !important;

}


</style>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
<ul>
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
    </li>
     <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_name)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_description)
    </li>
</ul>
 }
```

View _ItemPartial: addItemsBtn in this view

```
  <div id="tradeItem">

 @foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
<ul>
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
    </li>
     <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_name)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.item_description)
    </li>
</ul>


}
</div>

  <a class="AllItemsBtn" id="AllItemsBtn" href='@Url.Action("GetItemsToAdd")' >Add 
 File...</a>

 <div class = "ITA">/*load to this div*/</div>
```

Comment: I know its getting the right url because the alert is displaying it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: My answer below is before the poster updated his original post, so it may seem irrelevant. If someone run into the same problem try also reading the comments :)

Original post:

You have "return false;" before you call this code:

```
$('#ITA').dialog({
autoOpen: false,
draggable: true,
width: 'auto',
resizable: false,
dialogClass: "ui-dialog",
modal: true,
show: { effect: 'fade', duration: 300 } });
```

it will never be called.

Edit: and you need to change the selector to (".ITA")

Edit 2: Nicolae is right, put this code as a callback to the load call.
I don't get why the dialog library doesn't support url as an option.

Edit 3: You also need a call to preventDefault() on your event so the anchor tag won't redirect your browser

Edit 4: By the way, this line is weird:
$(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
put the css style before the button was clicked not after

Comment: I tried calling open before the return false and still didn't work and then removed return false and still the same

Comment: `$('.ITA').load(url, function () {
      $('.ITA').dialog("open"); // on success load, try to open the dialog here
    });`
courtesy of @Nicolae

Comment: I missed something, don't just remove the "return false;", move the entire $('.ITA').dialog...
and put it inside the click event.

Why do you need the $('.ITA').load ?

Comment: Im using the load the load the url

Comment: Im getting results but not in a pop-up I updated the view code with the `ITA` div. I think I'm getting confused

Comment: The `load` was the original code which wasn't working. I've made dialogs before the same way. don't understand whats going on

Comment: So where are the results displayed?

Comment: In the _AllItemsPartial view on a new page

Comment: Maybe you are also missing an "e.preventDefault", try after adding everything we said changing this: ....on("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...

Comment: doesn't even leave the page now.

Comment: That's great it shouldn't leave the page, it should pop up a modal :)
What happens now?

Comment: still not leaving the page. I thought for a moment it was the styles because I stripped all the styles but just put back in a bg-color but still no modal

Comment: Doesn't that open an empty dialog the instant the page is loaded?
try putting the $('.ITA').dialog code you have at the beggining, instead of the dialog("open") you have inside

Comment: I got it. Let me see what I did

Comment: sadly, I think it may all have had to do with css

Comment: I updated the code and it works now but the modal shifts the page when it opens and the class is not recognized. I don't know what's going on

Comment: Ok congrats! :) We leaped forward
What do you mean the class is not recognized?

Comment: No, it is. It was in two places but the screen still shifts on load. The screen behind the modal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36092/discussion-between-healix-and-eran-h)

Comment: Hmm sounds like a new problem concerning your use of the modal.
You tried googling for it? If yes I suggest you open a new question in stackoverflow because I'm not too familiar with jQuery modal

Answer (score 1):

Change your selector to class, 'ITA' is a class from what I see, not an ID

change

```
$('#ITA')...
```

to

```
$('.ITA')...
```

EDIT:

instead this:

```
$('#ITA').load(url, function () {
    });
```

try to add this:

```
$('.ITA').load(url, function () {
      $('.ITA').dialog("open"); // on success load, try to open the dialog here
    });
```

Comment: everything seems to work out the results from the query is returned but when it hit the partial I get a blank page